# How do I perform picking with the Tao framework (or OpenTK)

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, tao, opentk

Can anyone help me achieve picking using the Tao framework (or OpenTK) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the picking example in OpenTK (Examples.exe -> GL -> Picking). You can view the [sourcecode here.](http://opentk.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opentk/trunk/Source/Examples/OpenGL/1.x/Picking.cs?revision=2716&view=markup)